# Issue with ACTION_POINTER_UP,getX(0)

Tags: android, pinch

I am working with an imageview with pinchzoom. But i cannot use it with SDK version 4. geting error in ACTION_POINTER_UP,get(0) and MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK. It works fine when minimum sdk is set to 5 and Google API of API level 5 is selected.

My question is  **Can i trigger ACTION_POINTER_UP with google api[level 4]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that multitouch is since API 5. in API 4 you can get only 1 pointer by calling get() instead of get(0) and also in API 4 there is no ACTION_POINTER_UP, only ACTION_UP